# mongoDB - aggregation on aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have about 500 records in this format:

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId( "51ac1356c59151b66c0c9b6b" ),
     "device" : "SomeString",
     "carrier" : "Cell C(ZA)"
}
```

What i am looking for is a list of the distinct carriers, the number of devices per carrier and the count of devices per device

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
db.records.aggregate(
    { $project : {
       carrier : 1,
       device : 1,
    } },
    { $group : {
        _id : { carrier : "$carrier" },
        numDevice : {$sum:1},
        devices : { $addToSet : "$device"}
     } },
     { $sort: { numDevice: 1 }
});
```

Here's the output:

```
{ "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "carrier" : "Saudi Telecom Company (SA)"
                    },
                    "numDevice" : 229,
                    "devices" : [
                            "SomeString1",
                            "SomeString2
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "carrier" : "AT&FU (US)"
                    },
                    "numDevice" : 392,
                    "devices" : [
                            "SomeString1",
                            "SomeString2",
                            "SomeString3"
                    ]
            }

], "ok" : 1 }
```

This is **very** close to what i need / want, but ideally, i would like to see each "devices" section look like this:

```
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "carrier" : "AT&FU (US)"
                    },
                    "numDevice" : 315,
                    "devices" : [
                        {"SomeString1", 83},
                        {"SomeString2", 17},
                        {"SomeString5", 215},
                    ]
            }
```

Note that the devices array has objects, each object has a string **and** a count. In the example above, device `SomeString1` has `83` 'occurrences' in the collection for the 'AT&FU (US)' `carrier`

Currently, all i can find out is that the `carrier`'AT&FU (US)' has 392 "SomeStringX" associated with it.

**Is is possible to do this with a sub-call to the aggregation pipeline or do i need to use map reduce?** If i need to do map reduce, how would i go about doing it?

Comment: you can do this with aggregation framework. I can post the answer or I can give you a hint first if you want to try to figure this out yourself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to do it.  The key is that (a) you need to do $group twice and (b) you need to first $group by the thing you want to sub-total and then $group to get totals.

```
db.records.aggregate(
     {$group:
        {_id : {d:"$device",c:"$carrier"},
         subtotal:{$sum:1}}
     }, 
     {$group:
        {_id:"$_id.c", 
         devices:{$push:{device:"$_id.d", subtotal:"$subtotal"}}, 
         total:{$sum:"$subtotal"}}   
     }
)
```

Comment: **THANK YOU**  This is _exactly_ what i needed. I knew i could pipeline multiple group requests, i just didn't think to have the first ID be per device *and* carrier.  I would upvote this, except i still do not have 15 'reputation' points.  **MANY THANKS**

Comment: my pleasure. the cool thing about this aggregation trick is once you see it you realize how it can be used in all kinds of useful multi-level aggregations...